# XSL Sort treats lowercase separately from uppercase

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

My XSLT sorts lastnames alphabetically, but I just noticed that some of the names start with "de" and "von" or "van". These lowercase prefixes are being sorted and placed AFTER the Uppercase names. How do I tell the XSLT to sort all cases together?

Using XSLT 1.0

Here's the section that sorts the data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Data">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="Data">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Consultant">
<xsl:sort select="Surname" order="ascending" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>  
<xsl:template match="Consultant">
<consultant><Surname><xsl:value-of select="Surname"/></Surname>
<FirstName><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></FirstName>
<!--…-->
</consultant>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is some sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
<consultant>
<Surname>Arnon</Surname>
<FirstName>Lana</FirstName>
</consultant>
<consultant>
<Surname>von Armon</Surname>
<FirstName>George</FirstName>
</consultant>
<consultant>
<Surname>Arnon</Surname>
<FirstName>Lana</FirstName>
</consultant>
<consultant>
<Surname>de Armon</Surname>
<FirstName>George</FirstName>
</consultant>
</Data>
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a complete XSLT stylesheet and a complete input XML so that people can test this? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, added some more sample content and we're using XSLT 1.0

Comment: "von Armon" should come before "Arnon" - is this what you're saying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to normalize the case in the `<xsl:sort/>`

If your environment supports XPATH 2.0 then you can use either upper-case() or lower-case() like below:

```
<xsl:sort select="upper-case(Surname)" order="ascending" />
```

If your environment doesn't support XPATH 2.0, then you will need to use translate() like the following:

```
<xsl:sort select="translate(Surname, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" order="ascending" />
```

Comment: If your environment supports XSLT 2.0, then you can specify the collation to be used for sorting and discard the translate() "workaround" (see my answer for a better definition).

Answer (score 2):

Using translate() is a hack which you should resort to only if your processor does not support the `lang` attribute of `<xsl: sort>` - see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting depends on the XSLT processor you are using, in both 1.0 and 2.0.

Try adding `lang="nl"` (or some other suitable language) to the xsl:sort element to get language-sensitive collation for that language.

Answer (score 0):

Upper- and lowercase function is only available in XSLT 2.0 so you need to do it manually. Insert this lower-/uppercase variables and do it with `translate` in `xsl:sort`

```xml
<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

<xsl:sort select="translate(Surname, $smallcase, $uppercase)" order="ascending" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the issue is not lowercase versus uppercase letters. You're saying that "van", "de" etcetera do not count for the sorting.

If so, simply translating lowercase letters to *nothing* might work.

**Stylesheet** (adapted from @therealmarv's solution)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="''" />

    <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="consultant">
    <xsl:sort select="translate(Surname, $smallcase, $uppercase)" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="consultant">
    <consultant><Surname><xsl:value-of select="Surname"/></Surname>
    <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></FirstName>
    <!--…-->
    </consultant>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
   <consultant>
      <Surname>von Armon</Surname>
      <FirstName>George</FirstName>
   </consultant>
   <consultant>
      <Surname>de Armon</Surname>
      <FirstName>George</FirstName>
   </consultant>
   <consultant>
      <Surname>Arnon</Surname>
      <FirstName>Lana</FirstName>
   </consultant>
   <consultant>
      <Surname>Arnon</Surname>
      <FirstName>Lana</FirstName>
   </consultant>
</Data>
```

Comment: IMHO, they do count, but the default sort order is Unicode.

Comment: I meant to say: "prefixes" like "van" or "de" should not determine the position that is assigned to a name. It should be sorted according to the name that comes after (just guessing what the OP's intent could be).

Comment: NO, we need to honor the names as is. But XML is case sensitive and treats uppercase and lowercase as two separate flows. The first solution worked fine. van Helflin should be sorted as "V" not "H".

At least it should in our data flow. Thanks

Comment: @MathiasMüller I tend to agree with you on principle, but the implementation is more complex than just removing lower-case characters *en masse*; for example, "daVinci" should appear next to "DaVinci" and "Smith" needs to appear before "Snyde", not necessarily in the document order.